# how to solve "hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I got following  error while calling another groovy file in my Jenkinsfile-

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap.test() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [${REPO_PATH},
>   ${APP_NAME}]
>       Possible solutions: wait(), sort(), getAt(java.lang.String), keySet(), keySet(), keySet()

I am calling a function from another groovy file. following is mine Jenkinsfile and groovy functional file.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
Map modules = [:]
pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages{
        stage('calling function'){
            steps{
                script{
                    modules.test = load "testfun.groovy"
                    modules.test('${REPO_PATH}','${APP_NAME}')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**testfun.groovy:**

```
def call(def path,def app){
    stages{
        stage('build and deploy'){
            steps{
                sh''' 
                cd ${path}/${app}/
                mkdir testing
                '''
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Suggest me the right way.

Comment: try to put `return this.&call` at the end of `testfun.groovy`. scripts must return something. usually it's `this` keyword: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

Comment: I tried it but it also gives same error.